# boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::iostream does not work?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Referencing an [old (from 2008) discussion](http://old.nabble.com/Problems-with-boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::iostream-under-Boost-1.36.0-td19462107.html):

There is a compile error when trying to use boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::iostream

There was no solution on the discussion forum and I've run into the same problem, it seems.

Has there been a fix or solution for the compile error? How can I use
boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::iostream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was reported on the [boost trac webiste](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4196). Chris closed it as invalid and suggested using the existing boost::asio::local::stream_protocol examples.

Answer (score 1):

The class [`stream_protocol`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/asio/local/stream_protocol.hpp) defines no inner `resolver_query` type. That member type is needed for the [`connect` function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/asio/basic_socket_streambuf.hpp). The `connect` function is called inside the constructor with parameters of [`basic_socket_iostream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/asio/basic_socket_iostream.hpp). It seems to me, that the `stream_protocol` was not meant to act as a `iostream`. If you look into the [`stream_protocol`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/asio/local/stream_protocol.hpp) header you even see an `#if !defined(BOOST_NO_IOSTREAM)` around the inner `iostream` type. So try to use `endpoint`, `socket` or `acceptor` instead.

EDIT:
If you used a string, try connecting to an `stream_protocol::endpoint` instead. Using something different than an `stream_protocol::endpoint` will result definitely in this error. If this doesn't help first construct the object and after after that, use the `connect` method to connect to an endpoint.

EDIT: For examples of how to use `stream_local` try the [official example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/local/stream_server.cpp).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it. There is a new example in the current boost distro (libs/asio/example/local/iostream_client.cpp) - unfortunately this only covers the client. Would a server work analogous or do you have any hint how to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't ask in the referred forum, where they are with this issue? You can also look at the Trac system for pending issues. If you don't find the issue, make a new one. In this way you contribute to improving Boost.

Comment: Have you posted to the user list or the developement list?